# Forbidden response in post request-jMeter

Tags: java, http, post, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying hit localhost from jMeter with port 9090 and passing two user name and password parameters. When I run the test plan I'm getting the Forbidden response from jMeter.

My test plan is as follows,

[image]

And If run the above test plan the result is like this,

[image]

How to resolve this? Any suggestions please!!

Comment: what happens when you type `http://localhost:9090/node?name=admin&pass=admin` into a browser? (actually try it, don't assume). what do you type in the browser to log in? it appears you are hitting your server, but it is not letting you in. 403 is a server response, not a jmeter error. maybe the path is wrong, maybe the name or pass values. what kind of authentication does the server use?

Comment: also, this has nothing to do with java or jmeter-plugins, you may get downvotes for that!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm new to jMeter. Any thanks for your suggestion

Comment: From the following link, https://www.drupal.org/project/securesite I have given the server address as, admin:admin@localhost and port number as, 9090. Now I am getting error Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect authentication method for the server.

The way you have programmed jmeter will send a request to the server like:

```
http://localhost:9090/node?name=admin&pass=admin
```

However, your server is expecting a request like:

```
http://admin:admin@localhost:9090/
```

The former is an application authentication method, and the latter is server basic authentication method.

To provide the server with the correct request for Basic Authentication you can use the HTTP Authorization Manager, using your username and password. This will manage the entire security session for you during your tests. It will keep you logged on as you send further requests.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Basic Authentication challenge. Add a [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) to your test plan and put authentication details in there.